# Cannot access resource defined in app.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I am using Visual Studio 2010 RC1.

I define a resource "Brush2" in app.xaml_:

```
<Application x:Class="VideoThumbnails.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="Brush2" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.3,0.3">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#ffc0c0" Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In my Mainwindow I am trying to use that resource:

```
...
<Border Margin="4,2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4"
        ToolTip="{Binding Path=FullPath}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="{StaticResource Brush2}">
...
```

No matter what I do it always raises an exception at runtime (Resource not found). I changed
build action without success.

How can I use resources defined in app.xaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing you have done is incorrect.  You either have 1) screwed up the project build somehow while randomly doing things to try to get it to work or 2) something else is going on here and we'll never know without the exception details.

I would highly suggest you try to repro this in a fresh brand new WPF project.  Do the following steps (and ONLY the following steps):

Create a new WPF project, add the exact same brush to app.xaml, then open Window1 and bind the window's background to the resource.  Run the app.

It should work as expected.  If not, come back with the exception details.  If it does, compare this new project with your current one to see what you are doing differently.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion it works finally. I explicitly set the startup object in project properties to a certain class I defined myself. I changed that to "(not set)" and it works. How strange...

Comment: This actually makes sense.  Not Set would lead to the App.xaml being interpreted to figure out what to do on startup.  Setting it to your own class would result in that not happening unless you did it explicitly.

Comment: @DerKlaus - Thanks for your comment! I'd set App.xaml's build action to Page so I could create my own entry point. (this of course caused me to lose my shared resource dictionary from loading styles at design time). I did not know I could set the startup object in the project properties until reading your comment. This allowed me to set App.xaml's build action back to Application Definition! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm here now, too. Works in a new project but not where I need it. I don't see any differences. Where can I search now? I've already tried everything mentioned on this page. - Oh, and VS designer does it right and finds and applies the style, but not at runtime.

Comment: @LonelyPixel: Not sure.  Try opening the project files up and examine them.  The .proj files often contain more detail than the UI displays.  The only workaround is to move the resource to the .xaml file where it is needed.  And make sure you reference the resource *after* it is defined, otherwise you'll need to change it to a dynamic resource rather than a static one.

Comment: Just as a note for others (I know this thread is old): I just had the same problem. My application starts just fine, but App-resources can't be used. After some investigation (comparing with a fresh project) I realized these differences: 1. A static main method in the App.cs that is definetly not necessary | 2. Removing it causing it to miss a static main method for the entry | 3. A missing `x:Class="Project.App"`. Last one fixed second one and thus all problems. Now I can use my resources as usually. The custom stuff from Main is now in the OnStartup / Startup overload / handler.

Answer (score 22):

If you've set the Startup Object to a custom class you need to create the custom Application class and also call its InitializeComponent method, like this:

```
App app = new App();
app.InitializeComponent();
```

Update: As @qqww2 suggested the `InitializeComponent` call can be moved inside the `App` class constructor.

Comment: Or, better yet, add the `InitializeComponent();` method to the constructor of `App` class. No need to remember the function call after creating the object.

Comment: You're right, that's how I had started using it at some point. But I forgot to update this answer. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to find.

Answer (score 8):

I start my application **not** with a `StartupUri` in `App.xaml`, but with a event handler in `App.xaml.cs`.

When using `override Startup()` resources from App.xaml are **not** loaded:

```
public partial class App
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ...
    }
}
```

But when using event `Startup` the resources are loaded just fine:

```
<Application x:Class="OxyplotTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="OnStartup">
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class App
{
    private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that there must be at least one attribute for `<Application ...` e.g. you can simply set something like `ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose"`.

Answer (score 4):

I can concur that resources get messed up easily if you have something in App constructor. Move initialization of your own global objects into OnStartup method:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know there is an already accepted answer, but I thought I would add my solution as well. I had code that was working, but some configuration change broke the resource references in the designer. In executing code, it worked fine.

After some initial research, I determined that the BuildAction property for App.xaml should be set to ApplicationDefinition. My was set to Page. However, that causes some issues with multiple entry points. Main() was already defined in App.xaml.cs. The compile error was indicating another entry point in App.g.cs (which is an autogenerated file).

I ended up using the approach #3 described at http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/09/how_to_write_custom_main_metho.html. The basic idea is that you create a new class that is only responsible for startup. In my case, I named it Startup.cs. It should have code that is similar to this:

```
using System.Threading;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
        private static void Main()
        {   
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the project settings, change the Application -> Startup object so that your new class is selected.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and solved it, so I figured I may as well post my solution. I kept getting the `Resource not found` error only at runtime as described above. In my Windows 8.1 c# App, I was using a style I had defined, and it showed up fine in Blend and the designer view, but didn't work at runtime. I was trying to use this style in a SettingsFlyout I had created following [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872190.aspx). After getting that to work, I set up a field in App.xaml to hold onto my flyouts (Preferences and ColorSettings) so I wouldn't be making a new one every time.

```
public static Preferences preferences;
public static ColorSettings colorsettings;

public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    preferences = new Preferences();
    colorsettings = new ColorSettings();
}
```

After poking around and googling for about an hour, I figured out that I was creating the flyouts too early, and when they were created they couldn't access the application's resources. So I moved their creation down to `App.OnLaunched()` and that solved the problem.

I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about things, but it worked. So, try to pinpoint where you're trying to access the resources you want, and if you're maybe trying too early. Sorry for the vagueness and maybe incorrectness, I'm really new to WPF.